# does Rails 2.3 support a file-based session store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

Does Rails 2.3 support a file-based session store out of the box any more?
It looks as though it supports only use of active_record_store and mem_cache_store, in addition to the default cookie-based.
If it does support a file-based session store, how is that configured?

It seems as if it should be easy to find a definitive yes or no answer to this question but somehow I've had no luck googling for it.

(I won't go into the details of why I am trying to find an answer to this question... but I should add that I don't actually plan to use file-based sessions myself and don't need to be convinced that they are not a great idea.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like it

http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/39e1ac658efc80e4c54abef4f1c7679e4b3dc2ac/actionpack/lib/action_controller/session_management.rb#L10-22

but you should be able to implement file based through your own custom class (e.g. copy an old version of the included file store and update any interface breakage)